# instagram oauth issue (make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

Im trying to get basic data from instagram profiles, I am using a local webpack dev server to run my react app, I am also using Firebase functions, the function on firebase sends oauth/authorize request to instagarm's api, im getting a code response back and return it to my react popup, i then send the code to instagrams api for oatuh/access_token but im getting the following error:

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Im running localhost:3000 as https with an ssl, i've set the redirecturl in the instagram developer tools to https://localhost:3000/instagram-popup/

the popup is the page I'm, loading to get the access token, it does get the code from the firebase function correctly, but fails the last call... I have lost SO many hours on this issue, if anyone has been in this situation and solved it, or didnt even encounter it but knows what i can do to fix it, i would really appreciate any guidance here